# Evaluating a continued fraction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, continued-fractions

I have a continued fraction in List form: $[0;1,2,1,2...]$ (the $1,2$ are repeated).

Evaluating this should give $-1 + \sqrt3$.

I am not sure how to get that answer.

I am aware of to express $\sqrt3$ in such a form by doing [the following](http://planetmath.org/methodforcomputingsimplecontinuedfractionswiththeaidofcalculatorandpencilandpaper)

Comment: See [solving quadratic equations with continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solving_quadratic_equations_with_continued_fractions).

Answer (score 1):

every repeating CF will be a quadratic irrational.

The CF you wrote is this:

$$\alpha = 0 + \cfrac{1}{1 + \cfrac{1}{2 + \cfrac{1}{1 + \cfrac{1}{2 + \ddots}}}} = 0 + \cfrac{1}{1 + \cfrac{1}{2 + \alpha}}$$

now we can just work with that equation:

$$\alpha = 1/(1+1/(2+\alpha))$$

$$1/\alpha - 1 = 1/(2+\alpha)$$
$$(1 - \alpha)/\alpha = 1/(2+\alpha)$$
$$(2+\alpha)(1 - \alpha) = \alpha$$

to get a simple quadratic equation. The value of the CF is of course the positive root of that.